# useEffect goes in inifinite loop with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React/Redux application goes into an infinite loop on using useEffect with object references..

I am trying render pending todos for my application using `useEffect`.. and passing the array of todos as the second param in `useEffect` ..but why is not checking the values of the object ?

**Container:**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ actions: bindActionCreators(RootActions, dispatch) });
const Home = (props) => {
  const { root, actions } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos(actions.loadPendingTodo);
  }, [root.data]);

  return (
    <Segment>
      <Error {...root } />
      <TodoList { ...root } actions={actions} />
  </Segment>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

**Action:**

```
export const loadPendingTodo = () => ({
  type: LOAD_PENDING_TODO,
  data: todoService.loadPendingTodo(),
});
```

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  initial: true,
  data: [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'temp todo',
    dueDate: new Date(),
    completedDate: '',
    isDeleted: false,
    isCompleted: false,
  }],
  error: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isEdit: false,
};

export default function root(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_PENDING_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...action.data],
      };
...

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**getTodos Method:**

```
export const getTodos = (loadTodo) => {
  try {
    loadTodo();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // eslint-disable-line
  }
};
```

**Service:**

```
export default class TodoAppService {
  loadPendingTodo() {
    return store.get('todoApp').data.filter(todo => !todo.isCompleted && !todo.isDeleted);
  }
```

Can anyone please help me out how to resolve this issue.. and there is no official documentation for this case too :/

Moreover changing the `useEffect` to the following works but i want to render on every change

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos(actions.loadPendingTodo);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Try writing `useEffect(() => ..., root.data)` instead and see if that helps, since `root.data` will be a new array for every update.

Comment: no effect ... same issue

Comment: ITS URGENT... otherwise i have to move  back to traditional react..

Comment: LOAD_PENDING_TODO action creates a new `root.data` array after every fetch, as a result it launches fetch again

Comment: @Animir i believe thats how redux is used.. no state mutation is allowed in redux..

Comment: @MurtazaHussain That's true. And you need to change the logic behind your store in some way. It's unclear what was the reason to make it work like you do. If you don't need more than 1 temp todo then don't add them infinitely.

Comment: so that means i cant use useEffect with redux ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain You can. Just do this correctly. You would have similar problems with a class as well.

Comment: you please add some example here what you mean by logic behind the store ? .. moreover i need more that one todos to be listed...

Comment: The way the store works, i.e. Redux code. LOAD_PENDING_TODO changes the store infinitely when it's called infinitely. Don't change the store infinitely. If you don't need more than 1 temp todo, don't add more than 1 temp to do, as I already said. It's impossible to suggest anything more specific in your situation because it's unclear what was the intention to make it work like that. Please, use `@`, otherwise users won't receive notifications and won't answer your comments.

Comment: its still not clear to me.. but will do some research on it.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the `loadPedningTodo` redux actions in `useEffect` that was causing it to loop and directly setting the data in function from service..

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const { root, actions } = props;
  return (
    <Segment>
      <Error {...root } />
      <TodoList isEdit={root.isEdit} todo={todoService.loadPendingTodo()} actions={actions} />
  </Segment>
  );
};
```

thanks :)